# How to swich between cameras in CameraX API?

Tags: android, android-camerax

Based on [CameraX Basics](https://github.com/android/camera/tree/master/CameraXBasic) and [Introduction to CAmeraX](https://android.jlelse.eu/an-introduction-to-camerax-7ca657e6eee0) tutorials, I successfully created an activity that opens Camera inside that activity. I want to switch the camera between front and back on a button click. I use the following code to do that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     ...

     cameraOrientation = CameraX.LensFacing.BACK;
     StartCamera();

     switchCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
         @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view)
         {
             CameraX.unbindAll();

             cameraOrientation = (cameraOrientation == CameraX.LensFacing.BACK ? CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT : CameraX.LensFacing.BACK);
             try {
                 StartCamera();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
         }
     });
 }

private void StartCamera()
{
    previewConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder()
            .setLensFacing(cameraOrientation)
            .build();
    preview = new Preview(previewConfig);
    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
            new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput previewOutput)
                {
                    textureView.setSurfaceTexture(previewOutput.getSurfaceTexture());
                }
            });

    imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
            .setLensFacing(cameraOrientation)
            .setFlashMode(flashMode)
            .build();
    imageCapture = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(SampleCameraActivity.this, imageCapture, preview);
}
```

But, when I click on the button, the app becomes stuck (but it doesn't crash) and this error keeps repeatedly showing on the log:

`E/GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0–6996–1] updateAndRelease: GLConsumer is not attached to an OpenGL ES context`

I also switch flash mode and take picture using this api and all those works fine. I also have tested in multiple devices. Same error in all those devices.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few days ago, a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177668/how-to-switch-to-front-camera-on-camerax) existed, but the proposed solution didn't work for me. What worked was slightly modifying the method `bindCameraUseCases()` from the [official sample](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L341-L355) (which was linked to in the similar issue). Call `startCamera()` from `onCreate()`.

```
private fun startCamera() {
    texture.post { bindCameraUseCases() }
    //btn_take_picture.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() } 
    btn_swap_camera.setOnClickListener {swapCamera()}
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun swapCamera() {
    lensFacing = when (lensFacing) {
        CameraX.LensFacing.BACK -> CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT
        CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT -> CameraX.LensFacing.BACK
        else -> CameraX.LensFacing.BACK
    }
    CameraX.getCameraWithLensFacing(lensFacing)
    bindCameraUseCases()
}

// Slightly modified code from the sample
private fun bindCameraUseCases() {
    CameraX.unbindAll()

    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { texture.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val screenAspectRatio = Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)

    val viewFinderConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        setTargetRotation(texture.display.rotation)
    }.build()

    preview = AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(viewFinderConfig, texture) // See note below

    val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        setTargetRotation(texture.display.rotation)
    }.build()

    imageCapture = ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig)

    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture)
}
```

Note the class `AutoFitPreviewBuilder` is from the sample and can be found [here](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/utils/AutoFitPreviewBuilder.kt) 
(The samples is Apache 2.0 lisenced by Google so the usage should be fair)

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. I just want to know that u used `AutoFitPreviewBuilder` instead of `Preview`. Is that the only main difference from ur code to my code?

Comment: That do seems to be the main difference.  Given that the error you receive is linked to the `TextureView`'s `SurfaceTexture` used in the `Preview` I can't think of anything else that may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have looked at that class. But I didn't use it because that class is in Kotlin. I am using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for the imageCapture object and add
.setFlashMode(FlashMode.ON) to it's functions eg

```
private fun createCaptureUseCase(): ImageCapture {
    val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
            //when capturaing turn on flash
        .setFlashMode(FlashMode.ON)
            //set LensFacing and rotation
        .apply {
            setLensFacing(lensFacing)
            setTargetRotation(previewView.display.rotation)
            setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MAX_QUALITY)
        }
```